# Using React, Leaflet, leaflet-pixi-overlay, a marker popup closes right away after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, pixi.js, react-leaflet

I am working on a leaflet map, under React. For performance reasons, I've had to use PixiOverlay to draw my markers (https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay).
I'm facing a problem with popups though. With the following code:

- the Marker's click event is properly triggered when clicking on the marker
- if the map is dragged while the marker is clicked and released, the popup opens just fine
- BUT with a single 'clean' click, the popupclose event fires right away

My hybrid approach (react-leaflet, PixiOverlay) was working fine so far, but I can't work around this problem.

The following code is simplified, some elements are taken out of React's control to simplify the test code:

```
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import { Paper } from '@material-ui/core';

import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import 'leaflet-pixi-overlay';
import L from 'leaflet';

const pixiMarkerContainer = new PIXI.Container();
let markerTextures = {};

const testPopup = L.popup({ autoPan: false, pane: 'popupPane' });

const markerOverlay = L.pixiOverlay((utils) => {
  const map = utils.getMap();
  const scale = utils.getScale();
  const renderer = utils.getRenderer();
  const container = utils.getContainer();

  if (map && (Object.keys(markerTextures).length !== 0)) {
    if (container.children.length) container.removeChildren();

    const newMarker = new PIXI.Sprite(markerTextures.default);
    const newMarkerPoint = utils.latLngToLayerPoint([50.63, 13.047]);
    newMarker.x = newMarkerPoint.x;
    newMarker.y = newMarkerPoint.y;

    container.addChild(newMarker);
    newMarker.anchor.set(0.5, 1);
    newMarker.scale.set(1 / scale);
    newMarker.interactive = true;
    newMarker.buttonMode = true;

    newMarker.click = () => {
      testPopup
        .setLatLng([50.63, 13.047])
        .setContent('<b>Test</b>');
      console.log('Open popup');
      map.openPopup(testPopup);
    };

    map.on('popupclose', () => { console.log('Close popup'); });

    renderer.render(container);
  }
},
pixiMarkerContainer);

function PixiMap() {
  const [markerTexturesLoaded, setMarkerTexturesLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [mapReady, setMapReady] = useState(false);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(markerTextures).length === 0) {
      const loader = new PIXI.Loader();
      loader.add('default', 'https://manubb.github.io/Leaflet.PixiOverlay/img/marker-icon.png');
      loader.load((thisLoader, resources) => {
        markerTextures = { default: resources.default.texture };
        setMarkerTexturesLoaded(true);
      });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapReady && markerTexturesLoaded) {
      const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
      markerOverlay.addTo(map);
      markerOverlay.redraw();
    }
  }, [mapReady, markerTexturesLoaded]);

  return (
    <Paper
      style={{ flexGrow: 1, height: '100%' }}
    >
      <Map
        preferCanvas
        ref={mapRef}
        style={{ height: '100%' }}
        center={[50.63, 13.047]}
        zoom={12}
        minZoom={3}
        maxZoom={18}
        whenReady={() => { setMapReady(true); }}
        onClick={() => { console.log('map click'); }}
      >
        <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?" />
      </Map>
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default PixiMap;
```

Any suggestion? Thanks.

---

**Edit:** 
It looks like both the marker AND the map handle the click event (added map click logging in the source code). 
I want the map to handle clicks (which close popup's), but not when the click is already handled by the marker...

---

**Edit #2:** 
I have tried adding the following in the marker click handler:

```
event.stopPropagation();
event.data.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
```

But this does absolutely nothing... Looks like this is a basic PIXI problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I don't really see a 'clean' way of stopping the event's propagation.
The solution I have is to:

- disable the popup auto close when the map is clicked
- detect if the map's click is the same as the marker's; close the popup when it's not

Declare the popup with the following option:

```
const testPopup = L.popup({
  autoPan: false,
  pane: 'popupPane',
  closeOnClick: false,    // : disable the automatic close
});
```

In the marker click handler, record that click's position:

```
    newMarker.click = (event) => {
      // Set aside the click position:
      lastMarkerClickPosition = { ...event.data.global };
      testPopup
        .setLatLng([50.63, 13.047])
        .setContent('<b>Test</b>');
      setPopupParams({ text: 'test' });
      map.openPopup(testPopup);
    };
```

Add a map click handler, close the popup if needed:

```
    map.on('click', (event) => {
      // Find click position
      const clickPixiPoint = new PIXI.Point();
      interaction.mapPositionToPoint(
        clickPixiPoint,
        event.originalEvent.clientX,
        event.originalEvent.clientY,
      );

      if (
        (clickPixiPoint.x !== lastMarkerClickPosition.x)
      || (clickPixiPoint.y !== lastMarkerClickPosition.y)
      ) {
        map.closePopup();
      }
    });
```

This is somewhat dirty, as it assumes the marker's click event if handled first...